# Is there any convenient way to upgrade protocol using Angular 5 HttpClient?

Tags: angular, http2

I'm developing angular 5 application and now have searched a lot about how to upgrade a protocol using this framework.
 I want to use http 2. For these purposes i'm sending such headers by hands:

```
'Connection': 'Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings',
'Upgrade': 'h2c',
'HTTP2-Settings': 'base64EncodedSettings'
```

Unfortunatelly on the server side i can't see values from Connection and Upgrade. Is there anything that i'm doing wrong?

Here's few code samples:

```
private getHeaders() {
    return {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {
          'Authorization': localStorage.getItem(AuthorizationService.authTokenKey),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Connection': 'Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings',
          'Upgrade': 'h2c',
          'HTTP2-Settings': 'base64EncodedSettings'
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

And the call itself:

```
this.http.post(`some_url`, body, this.getHeaders())
```

Actually, what angular `HttpClient` is doing - it removes `Upgrade` header and overrides `Connection` with keep-alive.

How to avoid it?